# Driver pointer missing OpenGL C++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, opengl, driver

I copied an Hello world example for using OpenGL in linux, but I have a problem at the execution time.

Before, I made my link with "-lGL" and -lglut" and the compiler is happy and says no errors.

And then when I launch the executable I get this :

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  48
  Current serial number in output stream:  49
[2016-12-15 21:41:44] process exited with status 1, elapsed time: 00.21s
```

Here is the simple hello world code :

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void displayMe(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello world :D");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm on a Dell XPS 9530 and I use the following driver : Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

SO I don't understand why OpenGL wants to get the pointer of i965.

Edit : I just discovered that when I launch the binary from the terminal its works and the window appears correctly. The error coming only when I use the terminal inside of my IDE ( Gnat Programming Studio ). Strange

Comment: It sounds like there is something wrong with the way OpenGL is installed on your computer.

Comment: However I installed libraries via the official package manger of ubuntu.

Comment: Do not copy SO files to the executable directory, that might work on Windows but not on Linux. That said, it looks like you have incompatible libraries in your system. Did you do a full system upgrade lately?

Comment: @LnlB: Do other programs like glxgears work correctly?

Comment: @rodrigo I'm on a fresh install of ubuntu

Comment: @DietrichEpp glxgears works fine

Comment: If glxgears works but yours do not, maybe you are linking your program wrongly. Please run `ldd /usr/bin/glxgears` and `ldd myprog` and post the output.

Comment: @rodrigo: Good idea, and `readelf -d my-program | grep NEEDED` might also help elucidate this.